# Controlling Carousel in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jcarousel

I'm testing out the new carousel feature in bootstrap 2.0 and having difficulties making the nav arrows function correctly. The documentation is a little thin at the moment and i'm a newbie of sorts.

This is my html:

```
<div class="span9">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

  <div class="item active">

  <img src="img/testa.jpeg">

  <div class="carousel-caption">

  <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
  <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

  </div><!-- Carousel caption -->

  </div><!-- items -->

  <div class="item">

  <img src="img/testb.jpeg">

  <div class="carousel-caption">

  <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
  <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>

  </div><!-- Carousel caption -->

  </div><!-- items -->

  </div><!-- Carousel inner -->

  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>

  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>


  </div><!-- Carousel -->

</div><!-- span -->
```

I've activated the carousel in javascript:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel()
```

and that works. However the arrows don't move / cycle through the images when you click on them.

I'm sure it's something simple i'm missing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and discovered my version of jQuery was outdated. Perhaps make sure you are running the latest version, the Bootstrap Docs are running version 1.7.1 at present. After updating to 1.7.1 the Next and Previous buttons worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with the carousel but i got  it to work. now i cant figure out how to make it automatically cycle through the images after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

did you added the transistions lib in your page?? Is the last in the plugins list!

Comment: Yes - i've linked to js/bootstrap-transition.js. That doesn't seem to it though. The carousel does cycle photos but the navigation doesn't work...

Comment: Perhaps someone could explain how this works:    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this was a bug in Bootstrap 2.0.1. The answer given by Alexander Poslavsky in answer to another version of this question, worked for me.

Here is his answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482845/1166287

The gist -- delete or comment out line 86 in bootstrap-carousel.js:

```
if (!$next.length) return
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running through code in bootstrap.js (you can also look in bootstrap-carousel.js), and it's because the code for the slide method returns if you're on the last item in the list.

It works fine if you remove:

```
if (!$next.length) return
```

Just like David Cochran said.

Answer (score 1):

having the same problem today. My solutions:

- had to use jQuery 1.7.1 (and not 1.6.4)
- had to include bootstrap-transition.js

My question: how do i stop the carousel from autoplaying