# How can I keep carousel keep cycling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Apparently, the demo page on the http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel seems to have carousel stop rotating after it reaches the right most picture in the slide.

The demo used `$('#myCarousel').carousel()` to start carousel.

I tried

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel()
```

and

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle')
```

but carousel kept stopping when it reaches to the last picture.

I have seen some posts on the web that people actually want to stop it from cycling forever, which was posted like 3 weeks ago.
http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-bootstrap/browse_thread/thread/9eeedbb0e68789e3/bf99468117bd669a

What should I do so that my carousel will continue rotating after it reaches the last picture?

Comment: Why use this particular jQuery Carousel when there are so many others out there with a ton of more options?  Nivo Slider?  Cycle? jCarousel Lite?

Comment: I just wanted to keep everything with bootstrap.

Comment: Then what you want might be impossible.   Very few documented options here.

Comment: I do not understand why this got down voted twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually a bug that has been fixed in 2.0.2

You can try deleting line 86 in bootstrap-carousel.js which is,

```
if (!$next.length) return
```

See: [issue 2036](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2036)

Comment: Thanks! I knew this was a bug, and looking for the answer like this.

Answer (score 1):

We created an infinite jquery scroller for our corporate site. Our approach was, as each image was scrolled off of the screen we'd clone it, append the clone to the opposite side, and remove the one that just left the viewable area.

Comment: Respectfully, my answer adequately provides an answer to the question "WHAT should I do...". It's a solid recommendation of a way to solve the problem. The "HOW" would be a different question and fairly straightforward for anyone to implement familiar with jquery.

Comment: Not all readers are already _"familiar with jQuery"_ ... they come here to learn.   Besides, the question _"what should I do...?"_ is clearly referring to how to solve his Twitter Bootstrap issue.  Switching to another plugin is as valid an answer as telling him to give up using any carousel at all.

Comment: no, since the question is "how to keep the carousel cycling", not "Should I keep the carousel". Telling him to give up on the carousel plugin alltogether does not explain "how to keep the carousel cycling"

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

It's literally from the bootstrap site.  Makes no sense to me that this would not be instance specific.  But there is some room for improvement in the doc anyway.